# Continuity of [x] at 0

Tags: calculus

Isn't $[x]$ discontinuous at 0 with left hand limit
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^-} [x]=-1
$$
and right hand limit 
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+}[x]=0
$$

Comment: What is $[x]$? Is it the floor function?

Comment: Are the lhl and rhl values -1 and +1 just to make sure

Comment: Yes it very much is

Comment: Did you research before putting this question?

Answer (score 1):

If $x \to 0^-$ and $-1 \lt x\lt0$ then $[x]=-1 \to -1$

If $x \to 0^+$ and $0\lt x \lt 1$ then $[x]=0 \to 0$

So from these you can see that $[x]$ is not continuous at $0$

Comment: What function is $[x]$?

Comment: $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$ ..it has the property $x-1 \leq [x] \leq x$

Comment: So it is greatest-integer-less-than-the-number function

Comment: If I take a value close to 0 such as 0.230 as x approaches 0 from the right greatest integer less than or equal to it becomes 0 right? So rhl becomes 0

Comment: the value $[0.230]$ is zero

Comment: [-0.00000001] is -1 and not 0

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0^-} [x] =-1$

Comment: This function is discontinuous as every integer